# Bypassing Mixed Content in Chrome DevTools

Tags: javascript, https, devtools

I need to develop JS currency converter script that I could run in dev tools console.

I'm using exchangeratesapi.io **Free** API account to get currency rates. Free account doesn't allow SSL connection, so I'm using http instead of https. The problem is that I'm getting

`Mixed Content: The page at 'https://example.com' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://api.exchangeratesapi.io/v1/latest?access_key=API_KEY&base=EUR&symbols=USD'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.` error, when I try to run `fetch()` in dev tools console.

When I trying to use same endpoint in Postman, I'm getting correct results. How can I bypass Mixed Content error?

Comment: any ideas how to solve?